# How to read csv/xlsx data from XMLHTTP Request's response

Tags: javascript, csv, xmlhttprequest, base64, tobase64string

I have uploaded a csv/xlsx file into a browser and got a response which has a base64 encoded format as follows:

```
↵"data": "",
  ↵"files": {
    ↵"file": "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBBN4LPbgEAAAQFAAATAA....longstring...."}
```

Now using the response, I want content/data of my uploaded file as a javascript object to parse it. Any suggestions on how to extract the data from the above mentioned response data?

*Note:* I don't want to download the file, just want to read the contents of the file from response data (base64 encoded string)

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help some of you.

install and import xlsx package: `$ npm install xlsx`

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
let b64eData = response['files']['file'],split(',')[1]
let parsedData = XLSX.read(b64eData, {type: 'base64'})
let sheetName = parsedData.SheetNames
let fileContent = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(parsedData.Sheets[sheetName[0]])
```

But, still do post your answers for us to learn more possible ways of doing this

Comment: Can you clarify what is the XLSX in your code? Is it a library you are using?

Comment: @RickyStam yes it is a library. I've updated my answer to clarify it